# setInterval handle is a string and not a number in raspbian

Tags: node.js, setinterval, raspberry-pi3, clearinterval

I'm trying to clear a setInterval by getting the handle or ID, but setInterval is returning a long string. Here is my code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
  var myInterval;
  client.on('gettemp', function(data) {
      myInterval = setInterval(function(){
          getTemperature(client);
      }, 2000);
      console.log(myInterval);
  });
  client.on('stopread', function(data) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

When this is executed and I log myInterval which should be an integer, I get for myInterval in the console.log(myInterval):

```
Timeout {
  _called: false,
  _idleTimeout: 2000,
  _idlePrev:
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 2000 },
  _idleNext:
   TimersList {
     _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     _timer: Timer { '0': [Function: listOnTimeout], _list: [Circular] },
     _unrefed: false,
     msecs: 2000 },
  _idleStart: 14937,
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _timerArgs: undefined,
  _repeat: 2000 }
```

What is going on here? setInterval is working by emitting a temperature every 2000 milliseconds in the getTemperature(client) function, but I can't stop it because I can't get the handle for clearInterval(myInterval) because myInterval is a long string. Of course I can stop it with ^C with SSH where I start the node temperature.js application but I can't stop it with a button in the index.html file.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the `set*()` functions return, you should always treat them as opaque. It's still not immediately clear what the actual problem is. Your socket.io events share the same parent scope so there should be no problem accessing the interval return value for `clearInterval()`. One thing that is missing though is `clearInterval(myInterval)` immediately inside the `'gettemp'` event handler, in case of repeated execution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I see now that this is working fine. My confusion was that the first console log in gettemp was different from the console log in stopread so I assumed it wasn't working. I found that myInterval was being updated every time setInterval timed out. Strange that it would do this without the gettemp service being called again, I only call it once. I put the console log in the callback and saw a different myInterval every time it timed out. The stopread saw the correct myInterval. I assume it might miss if the asynchronous timing was just right.

Your last comment about repeated execution pointed out that any client could stop the service which I don't necessarily want. I'll put the setInterval in the client and have it request a gettemp from the service.